# Return position of MAX value in an array made up of a couple of SUM.PRODUCT formulas?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, formula

I would like to return a position of a MAX value in an array of results from SUM.PRODUCT formulas.

Basically,

Return position of ->

```
MAX({SUM.PRODUCT(),SUM.PRODUCT(), SUM.PRODUCT()})
```

Let's say last formula SUM.PRODUCT gives the greatest number and I need the position to be 3

How can I achieve that?

[image]

```
MAX(SUM.PRODUCTS(--(LOOKUP(A:A,C:C;D:D)=8),SUM.PRODUCTS(--(LOOKUP(A:A,C:C;D:D)=10),SUM.PRODUCTS(--(LOOKUP(A:A,C:C;D:D)=12))
```

So the result of above will be the MAX count, when I have it's position in the array, I want to retrieve value from D column using B column.

The output will be 8 because 06.00_14.00_I has the highest number of instances

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use:

```
=MATCH(MAX{YourArrayOfResults},{YourArrayOfResults},0)
```

However, I do feel like you have overcomplicated the matter. Care to elaborate a little bit more on your question and what you are trying to achieve through some sample data?

---

**EDIT:**

Based on your sample data and what you are trying to achieve, you can simplify what you are doing. Try:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX(A2:A12,MODE(MATCH(A2:A12,A2:A12,0))),C2:D4,2,1)
```

It will get even simpler in Excel365:

```
=@SORTBY(D2:D4,COUNTIF(A2:A12,C2:C4),-1)
```

[image]

Comment: SUM.PRODUCTS goes through a range of values that meet specific criteria and counts them. I need to compare three different scenarios and get the max of the count that's why I'm using SUM.PRODUCT three times. I then need the position of this value {1,2,3} and go to auxillary table for lookup value.

Comment: @timetravelprimer. It's best to show a simplified dataset with an example of what you are doing. I think I understand, but to prevent us going back and forth you should update your question.

Comment: unfortunately MODE returns #N/A. I've also tried MODE.SNGL and MODE.MULT with the same result

Comment: You might need to CSE-enter the formula. The answer is based around [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/most-frequently-occurring-text) source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following formula:

```
=MATCH(MAX(SUM(A2:A7),SUM(A8:A14),SUM(A15:A20)),CHOOSE({1,2,3},SUM(A2:A7),SUM(A8:A14),SUM(A15:A20)),0)
```

Replace SUM(...) with function which you want.

[image]